# Implicit differentiation

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The equation of a curve is $xy(x + y) = 2a^3$ , where $a$ is a non-zero constant. Show that there is only
one point on the curve at which the tangent is parallel to the x-axis, and find the coordinates of this
point.

I am completely lost.

Comment: How do you express the slope of the tangent ?

Comment: The slope is give by $ \frac {dy} {dx}$, no?

Comment: Differentiate the equation and then set the derivative equal to 0, I.e., the slope of the x-axis.  Start there anyways ...

Comment: @RiduanGonzalez: perfect. So this is where you start. Are you able to differentiate the LHS ?

Answer (score 3):

The curve is $x^2y+xy^2=2a^3$. Differentiating, we get $2xy+x^2y'+y^2+2xyy'=0$ using product rule.
  Now set $y'$ equal to $0$. You will get $y=0$ or $y+2x=0$.
$y=0$ is not possible because putting $y=0$ in original equation contradicts the given fact that $a$ is nonzero. Now put $-2x=y$ in original equation. You will get the point as $(a,0)$.

Comment: I'm at the point where I have $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {2xy + y^2} {-x(x -2y)}$, What do I do now, substitute $y = -2x$ into $xy(x + y) = 2a^3$? How do I get the value of $x$ after doing this?

Comment: You will get $x.(-2x)(x-2x)=2a^3$. You should be able to solve this.

Comment: Yes, thank you was braindead for a second then